# Why would $\forall x\log(x) = 0 \implies 2^\frac{1}{n} - 1 \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ for large $n$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Why would $\forall x\log(x) = 0 \implies 2^\frac{1}{n} - 1 \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ for large $n$? I'm reading a calculus text which used this in a reductio to prove the log function is nontrivial and I don't understand the implication. Note: the text defines $\log(b)$ as the derivative of $\exp_b(x)$ at 0, so no other definitions can be used in the answers.

EDIT: Heres is the screen grab from the book pdf:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but the expression on the left - $2^{\frac{1}{n}} +1$ converges to $2$, which is certainly larger than the expression on the right, which converges to $0$

Comment: I know, but I'm wondering how the implication is proved.

Comment: The left side of the implication doesn't make sense to me. Can you check it and be sure it's really what you meant? What's the base of the logarithm, $e$? If the base isn't $1$, then $\log x=0$ if and only if $x=1$. The right side of the implication doesn't involve $x$...

Comment: I'll put a screen grab from the text.

Comment: What text are you following? I see no $x$ in the screen shot.

Comment: How are you defining $\log$?

Comment: see the question

Comment: @RenéG How are you defining $\exp _b$?

Comment: @GitGud As the continuous extension of $b^x$ to the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the definition that the derivative of a differentiable function $f$ at $x \in \mathbb{R} $ is:

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} $$

Specifically this implies:

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0  \ \ \ \ \  \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \  \left|  \frac{f(x+1/n) - f(x)}{(1/n)} - f'(x) \right| < \epsilon $$

Define $ \log(b) $ as  $ \frac{d}{dx}(b^x) $ evaluated at $x = 0 $, as in your question.

If $\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \log(y) = 0 $, then certainly $\log(2) = 0$  .

Then by the limit definition of the derivative:

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \ \ \ \ n(2^{1/n} - 1)= \frac{2^{0+1/n} - 2^0}{(1/n)} - \log(2) \le  \left| \frac{2^{0+1/n} - \ 2^0}{(1/n)} -\log(2) \right| \le \epsilon $$

and then divide by $n$

Comment: Why $-\log(2)$? I think that's wrong.

Comment: remember, we're assuming $\log(2) = 0$ , so $\log(2) = 0$

Comment: Lol I'm stupid! But shouldn't it be log(2)/(1/n)?

Comment: yeah sorry i understand your question now. We subtract log(2) because that's the limit that $ \frac{2^{0+h} - 2^0}{h} $ approaches as $h \rightarrow 0 $


I'll edit the answer to make this clear

Comment: OOh sorry thanks for being so patient with me I get it now.

Comment: That's ok :)  . It also isn't important that he chose $2$, the argument will work just as well for other $b >1$, I think.